# Node Red HTTP POST for every JSON object (loop)

Tags: json, loops, node-red

I'm working in Node Red and I need to understand how to loop JSON object and, for each JSON object, make a HTTP request towards another endpoint.

In other words: here's the use case I will need to represent.
Node Red makes a HTTP post to get all devices.
All devices are returned in a JSON, with several information and a DEVICE_ID.
For every device ID, Node Red has to make another HTTP request passing the above id, to get all the resources for that device.

I'm in trouble since I expected Node Red to have a dedicated block for loops, but is not like that. So how can I make a workaround?

If I use the "function" block, and I type there the code to make my loop, how to "come back" to the flow view, using Http blocks? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In flow-based programming, you tend to avoid loops. The most "flow like" approach would be to split the JSON output into multiple messages.

If you are familiar with JavaScript, the easiest way to do this is with a function node. In the JS code, create a loop over the JSON and within the loop, use `node.send(msgobject)` to output a new message. You can remove the normal `return msg` at the end of the code as you don't need it in this instance. Obviously, you have to create your `msgobject` for each loop instance (or create it inline). When the loop exits and you reach the end of your function node code, Node-RED will continue on to the next node in the flow, you don't need to do anything special.

Otherwise, you can use the core `split` node (or one of the contributed split nodes) to split the data into multiple messages.

Answer (score 0):

Some specialized nodes exist for this purpose, for example [node-red-contrib-loop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-loop).